# How can I run my tests in incognito mode?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, coypu

The solution I'm testing saves the login so when I open a new browser the login is already done and my tests fail. browser.Dispose() doesn't work in this case. It would be better to test in incognito mode and I noticed that changing the driver's configuration is the easiest way to do it but I'm not sure how I can change it since I'm also using coypu.

This is how I create a new browser, I'm not sure how I can change this to include the running in incognito mode.

```
public static BrowserSession BrowserBackEnd;

    public static BrowserSession Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (BrowserBackEnd == null)
            {
                CreateNewBrowserSession();
            }
            return BrowserBackEnd;
        }
        private set { }
    }

    private static void CreateNewBrowserSession()
    {
        var sessionConfigurationChrome = new SessionConfiguration
        {
            Browser = Coypu.Drivers.Browser.Chrome,
            AppHost = "sitehere.com",
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
            RetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)
        };
        BrowserBackEnd = new BrowserSession(sessionConfigurationChrome);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### incognito

The [incognito](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito) argument causes the browser to launch directly in incognito mode.

- [Defination](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc?q=kIncognito&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=356):

  ```
  // Causes the browser to launch directly in incognito mode.
  const char kIncognito[]                     = "incognito";
  ```

---

To execute the tests in **incognito mode** of [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) you need to add the argument **`--incognito`** as follows:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--incognito` flag

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--incognito");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C://",options);
```